What does "joint-most" exactly mean?
Consider following sentence:

Lionel Messi is now the joint-most decorated footballer of all time after Paris Saint-Germain wrapped up the Ligue 1 title on Saturday. (SportsMole)

or

Britain's joint-most decorated female Olympian Charlotte Dujardin  pulls out of Paris games after 'error of judgement' (LBC)

I'm failing to find the exact meaning of "joint-most" both in wiktionary and paper dictionaries I got under my hand. Googling "joint-most" meaning also brings me nothing.
From context I can only guess that joint here means that this was an achievement accomplished  in some team effort (as opposed to an individual effort).
But it seems to me it would be beneficial to have actual explanation. What does joint-most exactly mean? Can it be used in some other context apart from 'joint-most decorated'?

Seems to be a clumsy way of saying that they equal somebody else in being the most decorated sportsperson in their field. IMHO joint most-decorated would be clearer.

The hyphen is incorrect. Typical expressions are: 'the joint most decorated athlete / the joint best performance / the joint least rainfall in June ....

joint here simply means "shared with another". Did you try looking up "joint"? Often  compounds won't be in a dictionary but the two components will be.

@StuartF yep, this is why I thought it's about team effort

I also think the hyphen is an error.  In this context "joint" simply means that the title is shared with another person.

It's not a word joint-most. They are using that as an adjective. Like: mouse-eating animals. But the hyphen is not really cool,

Is this a common construction in British English when someone shares a most-something position with another athlete? I have never seen "joint" used this way.  "The joint least rainfall in June" is the sort of thing you hear all the time on TV weather? And this has been going on for decades?

I also have never heard this usage in America. I would probably say, “tied for the most ...” (where “the” can be dropped in casual speech).

@TimR ‘Joint least rainfall’ would be quite clumsy and unusual, and I don’t recall hearing that sort of construction; but ‘joint most-decorated’, while perhaps not that common, doesn’t sound odd or out of place. ‘Joint first place’ is very common, though, meaning ‘tied for first place’, and ‘joint winner(s)’ seems perfectly commonplace to me in both BrE and AmE.

@JanusBahsJacquet  Thanks for  "joint first place": that's 100% "tied for first place" in AmE.  "joint winner(s)" would fly in AmE, as you say. Have you been stateside, or is your (pretty damn good) AmE ear just from reading and movies?

@TimR I’ve spent limited time there, but grew up with an odd admixture of BrE and AmE around me as a child (plus of course US media, which is everywhere), so it’s sort of a bit of both.

@JanusBahsJacquet  How's your ear with political insider James Carville, who is from Louisiana? I imagine he might be as hard to understand for a Brit as the language in the movie Kes is for most Americans.  Can you understand James Dickey in his appearance as the sheriff in the movie adaptation of his novel Deliverance?

@TimR Well, I’d never heard of either, but I just took a look at a video of Carville appearing on a news segment and this clip from Deliverance, and with the exception of the very last words spoken by the sheriff (“Oh, he’ll come in during Prom Night”?), I found both perfectly clear and easy to understand. I find something like Sweet Sixteen much more challenging.

@JanusBahsJacquet  "Oh, he'll come in drunk, prob'ly".   As for Sweet Sixteen in the link provided, that's Irish English,  or Scots, not AmE.

@TimR Yes, it’s Scottish – quintessential Glaswegian. I meant that I find that much more challenging (even though it’s from the British Isles) than any American accent I’ve ever heard. The closest I can remember from North America was a thick, rural accent from, I think, Nova Scotia or Newfoundland, but even that was more unfamiliar than undecipherable.

@TimR I'm an AmE speaker, I find this usage completely understandable (meaning tied) but totally alien.  "Joint winner" only feels right in a situation like a shared Nobel prize, not for two independent tied scores.

@LorenPechtel  When more than one person shares a named award, I would call them "joint winners". But I wouldn't call two runners in a dead heat the "joint winners" of the race when referring to the outcome of the race itself, though perhaps in the context of being awarded a gold medal.   "Joint first place" sounds very odd to me, unless "first place" is envisioned as a ribbon that is presented.

@TimR How are you in any way disagreeing with me?

@LorenPechtel  We would both say "they tied for first place" when describing the race proper but I don't find it too strange to call them "joint winners" when they are being presented with the medal.  Wasn't sure how you regarded the ceremonial aspect.

It looks like the same meaning of joint as in "joint owner"—the honor of being the "most decorated" is shared with another in their field. In other words, they are tied. (Like Kate Bunting, I am not a fan of their chosen hyphenation.)
This is backed up by the full article about Messi:

After Saturday's draw secured the title for PSG, Messi has now won 43 trophies in a glistening senior career - a tally which can only be matched by former Barcelona teammate Dani Alves.

Here's another example of "joint most [NP]", in the context of golf (not a team sport):

Victory at Hazeltine will make Tiger the joint most winning player in PGA history, with five titles alongside Walter Hagen and Jack Nicklaus.
—A Major Obsession: One Fan, Four Golf Championships


I see, thanks for clarification, I guess it's hyphen that actually lead to my confusion

Yes. The hyphen is misplaced. See my answer.

Since this is ELL, I'll point out that the past tense of the verb "to lead" is "led," not "lead." While the written word "lead" can be pronounced "LEED" or "LED," the latter pronunciation is reserved for the chemical element with atomic number 82 and symbol Pb (for plumbum, its Latin name).

I would expect that the hyphen is by analogy with 'second-most'. Personally I support the use of hyphens where they reflect the cadence of the sentence as I would speak it.

It is an error of punctuation. It should be written, "Lionel Messi is now the joint most-decorated footballer of all time.
This is because "most-decorated" is an adjectival phrase.
The collocation "joint-most" is nonsense.

Joint in this context means 'shared'.  Though I've never seen this usage before.  In American English, 'joint' is only used commonly for a few situations: A joint account (two or more people who share a bank account for instance), or a 'joint statement' (two or more organizations putting out a press release), perhaps a few others. When I use the word 'joint' in place of 'shared' in other ways, such as a joint car, or joint apartment, it doesn't seem correct.  I would not know what this would mean.  "Joint most decorated" also seems awkward and incorrect.  Only one can be 'most'.  I would write it this way: "Lionel Messi is now one of the most decorated footballers of all time".

Your version changes the meaning of the original. Joint most-decorated means Messi and another footballer (Dani Alves) tie.  Your sentence suggest there may be more than two footballers who have won 43 trophies in their career. Check with Laurel's answer.

It’s definitely not true that only one can be ‘most’. If two people have the exact same amount of something measured (a score, number of medals, money, whatever), and no one else has as much as they do, then they are both the most [whatever quality is being measured]. This is exactly the case here. Being or having ‘most’ (of) something just means that no other entity is/has more. And even in American English, terms like joint winner are perfectly normal, and even joint first (prize/place) not unheard of.

@Mari-LouA His sentence does not imply there are more than two, just that there is more than one.  I don't like his usage, though, because to me it doesn't indicate an exact equivalence.

I think this particular usage of "joint" is British.  As an American I understand it but only because I've heard it in British sources.
